# How to advice JUnit methods with Spring AOP

Tags: spring, junit, spring-aop

I have a class that extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests. I want to advice the @Before method for each subclass. 
However in my Aspect class I cannot inject any of these instances. I have looked at the beans created in the application context and I can't see any test beans. So how can I get them or how spring creates these beans?

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-context.xml"})
    public abstract class Ab extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
}

public class MyTests extends Ab {
    @Before //I want to advice this
    public void before() {}
}

@Aspect
public class BeforeTestsAspect {
    @Autowired //it won't find any bean of type Ab
    private Ab ab;
}
```

Comment: Spring doesn't create those beans, JUnit does. You should tell us what you are actually trying to achieve. There is probably another solution.

Comment: I basically want to achieve what is described in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505952/how-to-populate-database-only-once-before-test-methods-in-spring-test
But the solution is not acceptable for because, that would run the script for every class.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using aspectj instead of spring aop there is a good example of how to set it up [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

aspectj allows you to pointcut any class in your application or tests not just those created by spring.