# Populate database only once before @Test methods in spring test?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-jdbc, spring-test

I have the same problem that in this question:

[How to populate database only once before @Test methods in spring test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505952/how-to-populate-database-only-once-before-test-methods-in-spring-test)

But the solution is not acceptable for me because that would run the same script for all  my tests classes. 
What I want is to run a different script for every test class only once. 
The only solution that I have found so far is to add an if in the @Before method

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are willing to have a different `ApplicationContext` loaded (and cached) for each test (see below), your only option is to define a `static boolean` field and set it in a `@Before` method that populates the database if it is the first run in the class. I imagine that's what you meant by having an `if` in the `@Before` method.

Now if you are willing to have a different `ApplicationContext` loaded for each test class, you could define a unique `@Configuration` class or XML configuration file that populates the database for the given test class. You could then annotate your test class like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/standard-test-config.xml", "TestClass1-config.xml" })
@DirtiesContext( classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS )
public class TestClass1 { / * ... */ }
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { StandardTestConfig.class, TestClass1.Config.class })
@DirtiesContext( classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS )
public class TestClass1 { / * ... */ }
```

You can then use `<jdbc:embedded-database ...>` or `<jdbc:initialize-database ...>` in XML or `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` or `ResourceDatabasePopulator` (with `DatabasePopulatorUtils`) in an `@Configuration` class.

Of course, loading a different `ApplicationContext` for each test class like this may tremendously slow down your test suite, especially if the `ApplicationContext` takes a long time to load. So you'll need to take that into consideration.

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@BeforeClass` allows to run initialization code for a group of tests. This is an extract from the [javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html):

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup
>   (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the
>   independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization.
>   Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes
>   it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class. The
>   @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those the
>   current class.

Comment: `@BeforeClass` is typically not an option when using the _Spring TestContext Framework_ since you will not have access to the `DataSource` from the `ApplicationContext` in an `@BeforeClass` method.