# How to access spring ApplicationContext in junit @BeforeClass static method?

Tags: java, spring

I tried to get it by:

```
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Autowired
    public static void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AuditorTest.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
```

But it doesn't work as all other attempts.

How to autowire static `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: To populate db before jUnit tests?

Comment: You need to populate it once for the whole test case?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Are you using spring embedded db support?

Comment: Found [how to populate db before test cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505952/how-to-populate-database-only-once-before-test-methods-in-spring-test)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't autowire spring beans on `static` methods. You've to make it an instance method instead, and let it assign the value to `static` variable (that will work fine):

```
@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    AuditorTest.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
```

But I don't think this is what you want. I guess you should annotate the test class with `SpringJUnitRunner`, and `@ContextConfiguration`, and then you'll be able to autowire the `ApplicationContext` there:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(...)  // configuration location
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
}
```

Comment: This solution works for accessing the context, but what if you need it in @BeforeClass, then you can't access the non-static variable. You need this when you have a Bean class that is accessing the Context upon initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might have figured out a workaround by now.
May help someone else here.

I ran across the similar issue. Most of the spring framework options
provided does not allow static access of ApplicationContext.

The workaround is simple. Create your own ApplicationContext using
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext using the bean configuration but statically.

```
public class BaseTestCase {
    static {
        ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-config.xml");  
        // Do what you want to do with the context
        // Probably store in static variable to access somewhere else
    }   
}
```